# Include function value in json response

Tags: php, json

I have one PHP API which has JSON response. Its working fine as expected. There one field which I am calling in JSON with query called `qu_time`. Currently its returning date time from that field. I want convert time to ago function and want include it in JSON response. I have tried many possible ways for doing it but I am not a success as I am not PHP developer. My current API code is like below:

```
<?php

include 'dbconnection.php';

$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$offset = $_GET['offset'];
$orde = $_GET['order'];

mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES utf8");
$sql = "SELECT q.*,c.au_picture as picture FROM tbl_quotes q INNER JOIN tbl_category c ON q.qu_author=c._auid Order By q.".$orde." Desc LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$arr = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

and my time ago function is like below

```
function ago( $datetime )
{
    $interval = date_create('now')->diff( $datetime );
    $suffix = ( $interval->invert ? '' : '' );
    if ( $v = $interval->y >= 1 ) return pluralize( $interval->y, 'year' ) . $suffix;
    if ( $v = $interval->m >= 1 ) return pluralize( $interval->m, 'month' ) . $suffix;
    if ( $v = $interval->d >= 1 ) return pluralize( $interval->d, 'day' ) . $suffix;
    if ( $v = $interval->h >= 1 ) return pluralize( $interval->h, 'hr' ) . $suffix;
    if ( $v = $interval->i >= 1 ) return pluralize( $interval->i, 'min' ) . $suffix;
    return pluralize( $interval->s, 'second' ) . $suffix;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest to me how can I add time ago function value in JSON response?

Comment: If you add as first line in your loop `$r["qu_time"] = ago($r["qu_time"]);` ... does that give your desired result?

Comment: @ its causing some error....not working

Comment: Which error? Did you include the function definition? Is the field name correct?

Comment: @trincot its working fine....sorry I have missed one character in code...Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following line in the loop, which will do the function call and store the result back in the same array position:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $r["qu_time"] = ago($r["qu_time"]); // <---- call function, and store result
    $arr[] = $r;
}
```

Then the conversion to JSON can just stay as it was.